# How to test Android TalkBack Accessibility using Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android, accessibility, python-appium

I am using Appium with the Python API to do automated testing for Android Apps. Now I would like to do some automated testing of the TalkBack accessibility feature of the App.
I managed to activate the Accessibility Service during the test by setting the `disableSuppressAccessibilityService` capability.

So after starting the App through Appium I see the green boxes for TalkBack (are they called Live Regions?)

**Question 1:**

How do I check which element is the current TalkBack Live Region? A call to `switch_to.active_element()` gives an empty result.

**Question 2:**

How do I trigger the current TalkBack element? Normally this would be done by a double-tap anywhere on the screen, but when I send a TouchAction with a double-tap at any coordinates the element that is at the coordinates' position gets tapped instead.